# add a tailwind class with livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

i'm doing a tab bar to show some views using livewire but I don't know how to remove and a class for inactive tabs and active tab

```
<div class="tabs tabs-boxed">
    <button wire:click="tabView(1)" class="tab">{{ __('Activities') }}</button> 
    <button wire:click="tabView(2)" class="tab">{{ __('Schedules') }}</button> 
    <button wire:click="tabView(3)" class="tab">{{ __('Contacts') }}</button>
</div>
```

in this case I want to add `bg-green-500` and `rounded-full` to the active tab, but then remove those classes if the tab is inactive.

this is the livewire component:

```
class Clients extends Component
{
    public $view = '';

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.clients.clients');
    }

    public function tabView($tab_id){

        $this->reset();
        
        if($tab_id == 1){

          $this->view = 'activities';
        
        } elseif($tab_id == 2){

            $this->view = 'schedules';

        }else{

          $this->view = 'contacts';

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you tried somewhat like `<button wire:click="tabView(1)" class="tab @if($view === 'activities') bg-green-500 rounded-full @endif">{{ __('Activities') }}</button>` ?

Comment: a common format is: class="{{$view=='activites' ? 'your preferred class':' '}}"